# HashSet class in Haxe

Tags: haxe

Is there a predefined `HashSet` class in Haxe, similar to

```
s = set()
```

in Python or

```
import java.util.HashSet;
```

in Java?

I know, I can simply use `haxe.ds.HashMap` in order to quickly implement such a set, however I'm curious whether I really need to do this ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no set data structure in the standard library, but that doesn't necessarily mean you have to implement one yourself. The [polygonal-ds](https://github.com/polygonal/ds) library is excellent for instance, and comes with a [`HashSet`](https://github.com/polygonal/ds/blob/master/src/polygonal/ds/HashSet.hx) class (among many others).